# Why is $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{x} = \frac{1}{7}$ the same as saying: $(2)^{x} = 7$

Tags: exponentiation, problem-solving, fractions

Why is $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{x} = \frac{1}{7}$

the same as saying: $(2)^{x} = 7$

Sorry for the really dumb question but I'd like to see the process of how this is achieved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say we have two fractions in an equality:
$$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$$
where $b\neq0\neq d$.
We can flip them over, and say that
$$\frac{b}{a}=\frac{d}{c}$$
where $a\neq0\neq c$.

Let's apply that here. First, we distribute out the $x$:
$$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^x=\frac{1^x}{2^x}$$
Now we substitute this back in:
$$\frac{1^x}{2^x}=\frac{1}{7}$$
Flipping this, we have
$$\frac{2^x}{1^x}=\frac{7}{1}$$
To finish, think about what $1^x$ equals, and what $\frac{7}{1}$ simplifies to.

Answer (score 0):

$7 = \frac{1}{1/7} = \frac{1}{(1/2)^x} = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{-x} = \frac{1}{2^{-x}} = 2^x$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^x = \frac{1}{2^x}
$$

Then if you just cross multiply you get $2^x = 7$.

Answer (score 0):

Because $(\frac a b)^x = \frac {a^x} {b^x}$.

With that in mind $(\frac 1 2)^x = \frac {1^x}{2^x} = \frac 1 {2^x} = \frac 1 7$

and therefore $\frac 1 {2^x}*[2^x*7] = \frac 1 7*[2^x*7]$  and therefore $7 = 2^x$.